# Sql Exception: No Process Is on the Other End of the Pipe

Tags: sql-server, authentication, windows-services, ssms

I can not access my sql server connection from c# code. I get this error:

Sql Exception: No Process Is on the Other End of the Pipe

thats the connection string in my app.config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=BELLA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TLP;User Id=pascal;Password=test;Pooling=False"/>
```

When I use windows authentication: Integrated Security=True;

Then I can connect to the database.

BUT I can NOT use windows authentication because the opening of the sql connection is done from within a windows service which is run as LocalSystem. When I do this I get this error:

[Login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894651/login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system)

Its the first time I create a login + user in sql management studio so I am nearly sure I did something wrong and its my fault.

This is what I did:

1) Create a new login in the server`s security folder with sql authentication user:pascal and password:test.

2) Went to my database and create a new user in the security folder with user: pascal and login: pascal and schema: dbo

3) Did I forget something?

Solutions from other people:

1) I have also tried this link but no luck my Sql Select on the suspect_pages table is empty.

[Error: No process is on the other end of the pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974506/error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)

2) My Sql Server network configuration has ENABLED on the tcp/ip, names pipes and shared memory settings.

3) [SQL Server 2008 can't login with newly created user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719399/sql-server-2008-cant-login-with-newly-created-user?rq=1)

Number 1 to 3 did not help at all.

All this is done on my local machine. No network is here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you enable Shared Memory and TCP/IP providers in SQL configuration?

If not, try opening the SQL Server Configuration Manager utility and enabling Shared Memory and TCP/IP.  The order that works for me is Shared Memory (1) and TCP/IP (2) for both server and client.

Also, make sure you are creating both a SQL LOGIN and DATABASE USER for PASCAL with correct rights.

Check out my blog article on creating logins.  http://craftydba.com/?p=656

The snippet below will blow away and recreate your login/user with the correct default database, default schema and read/write privileges.

```
-- Which database to use.
USE [TLP]
GO

-- Delete existing user.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'pascal')
DROP USER [pascal]
GO

-- Which database to use.
USE [master]
GO


-- Delete existing login.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'pascal')
DROP LOGIN [pascal]
GO

-- Add new login.
CREATE LOGIN [pascal] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[TLP]
GO

-- Which database to use.
USE [TLP]
GO

-- Add new user.
CREATE USER [pascal] FOR LOGIN [pascal] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

-- Add to database read / write roles
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'pascal'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'pascal'
GO

-- Add to database owner role?  
-- Only give out if application needs a high level of privileges.
-- EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'pascal'
-- GO
```

Server level protocols.

[image]

Client level protocols.

[image]

I never choose NETBIOS since it is a non-routable protocol.

If you are still having issues, please post a screen shot and more details.

Comment: Right click, the order option shows under client.  There is not such thing for server.  I do not think it is important.  Since shared memory is only used if you are logged into the server.  TCP/IP is used everywhere else.

Comment: I did all your tips (see my init post). Then I run your script and it works. My windows service can connect and fetch data via browser :) I looked at the script but still could not find something special I have not done before via the management studio GUI. But its nice to have this script now thanks for this too.

Comment: Read alot of stuff on th e net about Enabling `Shared Memory` while on my project my problem was actually having the wrong USER under security of sql server just because i restored a backup from a different server which had similar User as admin. so i removed and recreated the security and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an unusual scenario but I just got this exception and tracked it down to an invalid database name in the Initial Catalogue value of the connection string.